# React app what is the best way to add large text blocks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app I am creating for fun and it will have a series of maps I created with stories.  I am wondering the best way in react to deal with pages that have large volumes of text.  Currently I just create a new foo.js and manually add text with CSS.  So im adding Div's and Headings and Paragraphs.

The text pages are say 3 - 5 pages in length and I typically create them in word then cut and paste into visual studio code and then add all the CSS decorators by hand.

I must be doing this very wrong.  I am wondering if I add text to S3 as a file and then in my react app just create a component that has access to the S3.txt. If I do this im not sure how to auto format it to keep spaces and paragraphs.

So what is the best way to create and add large text (stories) to a react app.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing much more about your project, it's rather hard to answer...but if you're wanting to use CSS to format your stuff, you might be able to use Markdown to -author- the content, then use a parser to render it.

Depending on the parser, you could include inline in bits where it's needed, otherwise just style the tags it generates, and keep the whole thing you've rendered inside a `<div>` to make it easier to select only the stuff you really want to select.

S3 could be a decent place to keep stuff, then you could write some code to fetch it in your React components, but I'd say that's probably outside the scope of this question.

I'd just look into Markdown (and available parsers) as well as client libraries for S3, etc:

https://github.com/markedjs/marked -- Markdown parsing library

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3 -- Current NodeJS SDK for AWS

Comment: So the site is for fun and I guess my question is now im writing lots of text in word and cutting an pasting right into visual studio then im formatting each page by hand. and I plan to have many many pages of text

Comment: Right, and what I'm saying is that you could just write them directly using Markdown, (instead of Word formatting), then use CSS to style rendered Markdown in React components.

You could store that Markdown however.   Files in S3 (which would need to be read using something like `fs.readFile`, in a database, however.

Comment: ok I will give that a try I have not used it before. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.   Do me a favor and accept this answer if you don't mind!